# ANTLR4 with Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, antlr4

I am currently trying to use my [ANTLR4](http://www.antlr.org/) parser/lexer in an Unity project. 
The steps I have taken are:

- Generate the parser and lexer from the grammar in a separate project and copying the Lexer, Parser and the visitors/listeners into the Unity project
- Since obviously the Antlr4 runtime is missing I added the Antlr4.Runtime.v3.5.dll since Unity uses .NET 3.5
- I fixed an error in the parser since IReadOnlyList could not be resolved. I just changed it to an IList

After all these steps, Unity presents me with the following error:

```
-----CompilerOutput:-stdout--exitcode: 
-1073741819--compilationhadfailure: True
--outfile: Temp/Assembly-CSharp.dll

compute_class_bitmap: Invalid type 13 for field 
Antlr4.Runtime.Recognizer`2[Symbol,ATNInterpreter]:_interp
```

can anyone help me with this matter? It is very important, that I get this parser up and running because otherwise I'd need to write the parser on my own which would be extremely annoying...

Comment: Thank you, kind regards etc. are best avoided in the post.

Comment: can you give more information? For instance, Unity log file when you get this errror.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the C# runtime for ANTLR, which can be found on github here:

https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs

The Readme file at that link has a lot of information about installing the runtime.  I will refer to this Readme a couple of times as I give you a step-by-step list.

I am assuming you are using Windows.  You cannot currently compile an ANTLR4 parser for C# using Mac.

1) Install Visual Studio Community (if you haven't already) and at install time make sure to install:

- Core Visual Studio editor (default)
- .NET desktop development (under Workloads)
- NuGet Package manager (under Individual Components -> Code tools)

2) Create a new Project.

- Select Windows Classic Desktop
- Select a .NET Framework app
- Once Project is created, right-click project name and select Properties and take note of your version of .NET Framework (mine is 4.6.1)

3) Use NuGet to install ANTLR4.  Install a recent stable version of ANTLR4 (mine is 4.6.4)

- Right click the top-level solution node in the Solution Explorer window and select Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...
- Select Browse and in the search box type Antlr4
- In the search results there will be several options.  Click on the one whose name is exactly Antlr4
- In the right-hand pane, choose the version to be the latest stable version (4.6.4) and then click Install

4) Add your grammar file (.g4) to your Project by clicking Project -> Add Existing Item... and navigating to your .g4 file.

5) From the github Readme at the link posted above:

*If you have the ANTLR Language Support extension installed, this step is automatically performed.* Otherwise, you will need to right click the grammar file in Solution Explorer and select Properties. In the properties window, configure the following items.

- Build Action: Antlr4  (If Antlr4 doesn't appear as an option in the dropdown list, restart Visual Studio then try again)
- Custom Tool: MSBuild:Compile
- Custom Tool Namespace: The complete name of the namespace you want the generated classes to be located within

6) Restart Visual Studio and reload Project

7) Select Build -> Build Solution

8) Look in ~/repos/projectName/projectName/obj/Debug to find the generated files

- copy *.tokens and *.cs to a new folder
- also copy repos/projectName/projectName/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs to that new folder
- Open AssemblyInfo.cs and add the line "using System;" at the top and the line “[assembly: CLSCompliant(false)]” at the bottom

9) Move to Unity and import the folder you created in the previous step.

10) Open directory where you've installed Antlr4, and find subdirectory Antlr4.Runtime.4.6.4/lib (where you may need to replace 4.6.4 with your version of ANTLR4) and then choose the folder of the corresponding .NET version as used in step 2 (in my case the closest one is net4.5).  Drag Antlr4.Runtime.dll from that subdirectory into your Unity project.

And you should be good to go for using ANTLR4 inside Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you've already created your parser in another project, and only want to use generated classes with Unity, it's as simple as putting *Antlr4.Runtime.Standard.dll* file into your Unity folder *Assets/Plugins*. This worked for us in *Unity 2019.3.9f1*.